# Mod-rewrite slash at the end

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've got:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/$ index.html
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)$ index.html
```

and it works fine, when I request i.e.:

```
localhost/library/contact
```

but crashes, when attempted to request the same URL, but with slash at the end - the file loads, but with no styles, scripts etc.

I figured it's because I haven't got absolute pathes to every image and script in the document.

Is there a way to get the url with slash at the end to work just like if it wasn't there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make the slash optional with a ?

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.html
```

Comment: It shortened the code to one line, but the styles&scripts in index.html still not load.